Should I mention the reason I am transferring from my current PhD program in my statement of purpose?
I am currently in a PhD program in the US. I am also applying to PhD programs that start in Spring 2025 at other universities, because the situation in my current PhD cannot be salvaged. My question is about whether I should explain the reasons for leaving my current PhD program, and if so, how to summarize these reasons. The following is a brief (yes, this is as brief as I can get) explanation of what these reasons are.
More specifically, I started my PhD in 2021 with supervisor S1. After 1 year of work, supervisor S1 and I published a conference paper together. However, 2-3 months before we submitted the paper, supervisor S1 informed me that he is changing his research area to a different one, one that requires a heavy time investment in my part to get started in and get good at. I am also not particularly fond of this new area.
Supervisor S1 informed me that, if I wanted to continue working with him beyond this paper, I would need to change my research focus with him. However, I did not want to because of the aforementioned reasons, so I decided to look for a new PhD supervisor in my current area, or a close area, in the department.
I found co-supervisors S2 and S3 in the department, and they told me that we would work on a project that involves research areas A2 and A3, where co-supervisor S2 is specialized in area A2 and co-supervisor S3 is specialized in area A3. I agreed to work on them based on this premise.
However, it turned out that the project only involved area A3 and not area A2 at all. Moreover, supervisor S3 was completely absent during the last 2 years of my PhD: he would rarely answer my emails, and when he does, he would tell me to go talk to someone else in the department specialized in area A3 because he can't help me. Overall, he had very little involvement in my PhD.
What ended up happening for the last 2 years is that supervisor S2, who is specialized in area A2, would try to drive the project that only involves area A3. Areas A2 and A3 are different enough that one cannot be realistically specialized in both. I know this because supervisor S2 said that they are not specialized in area A3 several times before. Nevertheless, supervisor S2 kept trying to give me orders in area A3, but these orders were almost always incorrect or would lead to a dead-end.
This situation continued for the last 2 years, and before I started working with supervisors S1 and S2, I had published 3 papers in 3 consecutive years. By now, I've had enough, and I saw no hope in finishing my PhD with these people. So, I decided to move on.
Any suggestions on whether I should mention this in my statement of purpose? If so, how can I go about this given that the reasons are a bit complicated?

You can surely make this shorter, no? "My original PhD supervisor has shifted research directions such that our interests aren't aligned, and there aren't any suitable alternative advisors locally."

I suggest that a very short statement might be better, explaining that the available supervisors have changed focus and your career goals are elsewhere. Then spend the rest of the SoP on that, explaining your goals for study and future career. Keep the explanation to a sentence or two, but be prepared for questions that might arise in any interview or other follow-up. You might mention that the university you are applying to better meets your goals.
A statement as long as you have written here, however, would, IMO, be counterproductive and the bulk of your statement forward directed.

Buffy, thank you very much for the advice. I've asked several questions before on this site, and you have always provided sound advice every time. I just want to follow up with another question that you could perhaps help me with: There is a section...

...in the PhD application next to the SoP that states: "Please describe any experiences and/or challenges that may have shaped your intellectual and personal development (250 words max)". Would a summarized version of the explanation in my question go here instead? I would prefer to highlight as many of my accomplishments as possible in the SoP, and leave the reasons for leaving for this part of the application, but I'm not sure.

Another option is the section asking: "Please address any concerns you may have in your application. If, for example, you do not believe that your academic credentials demonstrate your true capabilities, please explain why. Also, describe any gaps in your academic career and work experience or any extenuating circumstances in your profile of which the admissions committee should be made aware. (250 words max)". What do you think?

I'm not sure any of that is relevant in your case. But for the first thing, keep it positive, not negative. Things that push you toward your goal formation. The second would only apply, I think, if you don't get good letters from those supervisors. Keep it positive. Keep it forward looking.

If I were you, I would write a short paragraph to explain the situation. It’s very natural for people to be curious about the reasons behind, and giving a bit more context demonstrates honesty and transparency. You don't want others to misunderstand you. You may ask your letter writers to mention this as well.
